# Angular7 + AngularFire2 can't add entry in Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to add a new entry in Firebase database with AngularFire2. But it doesn't seem to work.

My Firebase project is read-write open, it means anyone can edit its content.

I've created the following method within my component:

```
add(testInputElement: HTMLInputElement) {
  const test = courseInputElement.value;
  this.angularfirestore.collection('test/')
    .add({ value: test })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
}
```

When called it doesn't add to Firebase and doesn't output in the console.
What's wrong here?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#adding-documents-to-a-collection

Comment: The code looks OK at first glance. Since you say "Firebase database", but write to Cloud Firestore: where are you checking that the data wasn't added? Be sure to check on the *Firestore* console: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/firestore/data

Comment: @RenaudTarnec That's exactly where I've took the example.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've just created Cloud Firestore and now it's working, it's strange that I didn't get any console error though. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that indeed sounds weird. I'd expect your `catch()` to be triggered with a rather nasty error if the database doesn't exist yet. Anyway: good to hear you got it sorted.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

My findings may help you.
In a similar situation, I could not add or set with no output.

After launching the Angular app in the secret window, I was able to write.
The tab opening the Firebase console and the tab opening Angular may interfere.